# TeamCity on Production Server

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

Quick question: is it advisable and reliable to install TeamCity Server & Agent on the production Web server (VPS running Windows 2008, 2GB RAM, .NET 4), instead of a separate build server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't prefer it because the Team City config can contain internal server names that can point to your SVN server, etc.  I'd really prefer to throw it on a different machine even if it's a more modest machine with something like desktop specs.

Answer (score 1):

That would not make any sense at all.

The build server will have all kinds of sdk and tools installed.

A webserver would have as little programms installed as possible.

Answer (score 1):

There're many reasons not to do this.

- Security. Usually to build code you will need to have certain permissions that you won't like to give anyone on a production box.
- Building code can generate undesired load on your prod box. And, maybe not as important, at peak times your builds could slow down if your prod box is under stress.
- Both servers might need different components (e.g. SDKs vs just the essentials to run your app)
- Patches. Both boxes might go through different update cycles. You might have to restart your build machine for some reason.

If you aren't in a position to get an extra box, consider using an old low speced dev box, your source control server or even running it from one of the developer computers could be a better option.